# Catching an unhandled IOErrorEvent in Flash AS3

Tags: http, actionscript-3, flash

> Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never
> Completed.

That's what I see every time I try to load an image that doesn't exist using a Loader.  I'm getting a list of URLs and can't validate if they're pointing to anything useful. Whenever it encounters a 404 it gives me that error.

I have tried to catch the error with every available `IOErrorEvent` there is (there are 7 of them),but none of them seem to capture the 404.  Is there some other network event that I can be looking for to catch this condition?! I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

What I'd really like is to be able to catch the event regardless of its description and just deal with it... sort of like

```
myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.*, dealWithError);
```

But that's illegal. I even tried catching

```
HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS
```

but that never calls back because, I guess, it gets the HTTP status after it deals with the error events, so, as it fails on the "unhandled" error event, it just gets lost.  Are there events that aren't in the IDE that I'm overlooking?

All help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a `Loader` or a `URLLoader`?

Comment: I'm using Loader because I'm loading an image into the object. Should I use URLLoader and then stream the byte array into the MC? I'll do that if that's the solution

Comment: interesting... URLLoader DOES capture the IO_ERROR and handle it correctly... I guess the bytestream approach (what a HORRIBLE kluge!) is the answer... write it up, I'll give you the checkmark. :)

Comment: normally, the method suggested in my answer should work for a loader :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if you are using a loader; try adding the eventListener to the contentLoaderInfo of the loader, e.g.

```
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOErrorHandler);
```

Comment: a HA! that's where they hid it... very clever! (too clever by half, in fact).

Comment: i knew the event.complete was fired there, so it was only logical the ioError was fired there too ;)

Comment: Yeah even after being a flash developer for 2+ years, I still occasionally make this mistake. SUPER irritating.

Answer (score 5):

You must listen for the [IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html#IO_ERROR) of your [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event%3aioError) object.

```
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOErrorHandler);
function loaderIOErrorHandler(errorEvent:IOErrorEvent):void{
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + errorEvent);
}
```

If you trace the event object, then it should give you some information about what is going on.

Comment: I wasn't using URLLoader (though that turned out to be an alternative solution... reading the bytestream and loading THAT into a loader), it's the Loader object that I was using directly and it is not catching the IO_ERROR

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandlerIOErrorEvent);
```

[EDIT]
Also include contentLoaderInfo events?

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler );
```

Comment: yes, along with the 6 other IOErrorEvents. NONE of them are the culprits, and I can't figure out how to actually find out WHAT error it's seeing.

Comment: can you post all related code to you myLoader object. Without your code at this point we are just guessing. My gut is telling me you are not scoping something correctly. Also editing my post with more info.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` [*should* work](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=192478). Also make sure you're using a `URLLoader` to retrieve the image.

**Based on the example from the comments:**

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        public function Main() {
            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.java2s.com/image2.jpg"));

           urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
           urlloader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, imageNotFound);
       }

       private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
           var loader:Loader = new Loader();
           loader.loadBytes(urlLoader.data);
           addChild(loader);
       }

       private function imageNotFound(ev:Event):void{
        trace("File not found.");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dr.Dredel, Make sure you're using a `URLLoader` like in the example above.

Comment: agreed, but please add the code to actually draw the image, otherwise this is pointless! :)  Here's an example...http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flash-Flex-ActionScript/Network/LoadingImages.htm

Comment: oh, I see... sorry, I was overlooking you loading it into the Loader... ok... well... if anyone looks at this answer, please note that there is one missing line here whereby you have to set the format to BINARY or you'll get an exception trying to load the data into the Loader... otherwise, the above works.

Comment: ah crap... the answer from Michiel Standaert is the "correct" answer to my actual question, but I upvoted yours as it's also a great solution.